# Firebase saving the same node to different places

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Say I had a blogging application linked with Firebase. When I make a post, I want it to go both to the public feed and to my profile. How should I handle saving the same post in two different places? Should I make two copies of the posts's node, or should I make one node and save a reference to it in my profile?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Duplicating data in a NoSQL system is common practice. HOWEVER, don't do it just to do it. If you can work with a reference it will make the code and the databases FAR easier to maintain. This is going to be really tough to answer without understanding the scope of the project, your Firebase structure and some code.

Comment: Okay. I can see how maintenance would be much nicer, but is it also faster with the use of references?

Answer (score 2):

Since I don't know what language you are using I will just make this example with javascript.

What you are wanting to do is called a 'Multi location update'. You can read about [multi location updates here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/09/introducing-multi-location-updates-and_86.html).

```
const postKey = ref.push().key
const postObject = {
  title : "Hello",
  body: "Body here"
}
const updates = {
 `posts/${postKey}`:postObject,
 `users/${userId}/posts/${postKey}`: postObject
}
ref.update(updates)
```

Comment: So this is the approach where I make two copies of the object?

Comment: Just re-read your question, you can take either mine or Alex's approach below. Both are valid use cases and one might suit better than the other depending on your specific case

Answer (score 0):

If is needed, you can use the same object on two different `DatabaseReference` when adding data to Firebase database.

```
usersRef.child(uid).child("posts").setValue(postObject);
```

and

```
postsRef.child(postId).setValue(postObject);
```

Another approach is to have a database that shoul look like this:

```
Firebase-root
   |
   ---- users
   |      |
   |      ---- uid1
   |            |
   |            ---- posts
   |                   |
   |                   ---- postId1: true
   |                   |
   |                   ---- postId2: true
   |
   ---- post
         |
         ---- postId1
         |      |
                ---- Post 1 Object
         |
         ---- postId2
                |
                ---- Post 2 Object
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Which way is better? Making two copies or making one node and a reference?

Comment: If we speak about scalability and having in mind that keeping the data as flatten as possible in Firebase is an important rule, second solution would be better. But if you need to have additional data from that object, you can use also the first one.

Comment: Have you managed to solve this?